# Ruby class is outputting files as well as directories

Tags: ruby

Why does below class output directory's as well as filenames on line "print "\n"+f" ?
I just want to output the files but directories are also being outputted.

```
class Sort



  require 'find'

  directoryToSort = "c:\\test"

   total_size = 0

   Find.find(directoryToSort) do |path|
     if FileTest.directory?(path)
       if File.basename(path)[0] == ?.
         Find.prune       # Don't look any further into this directory.
       else
       Dir.foreach(path) do
       |f|
       # do whatever you want with f, which is a filename within the
       # given directory (not fully-qualified)
         if !FileTest.directory? f
         print "\n"+f
         end
       end
         next
       end
     else
     end
   end

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says right there in a comment:

```
# do whatever you want with f, which is a filename within the
# given directory (not fully-qualified)
```

key being "not fully-qualified" part. you need to do something like:

```
if !FileTest.directory? (path + File::SEPARATOR + f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the Ruby standard [File.directory?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/File.html#method-c-directory-3F) method instead.

Answer (score 1):

you need `File.directory?( filename )` to check if it's a filename

you probably want to do something along these lines....

this is a helper method for doing recursive directory descend and executing a block depending 
on if the filename matches a certain Regular Expressions.. a bit overkill for you, but maybe this helps.

```
# recursiveDirectoryDescend                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
#      do action for files matching regexp
#
# (not very elegant solution, but just for illustration purposes. Pulled from some very old code.)


def recursive_dir_descend(dir,regexp,action)
  olddir = Dir.pwd
  dirp = Dir.open(dir)
  Dir.chdir(dir)
  pwd = Dir.pwd

  for file in dirp
    file.chomp
    next if file =~ /^\.\.?$/  # ON UNIX, ignore '.' and '..' directories

    filename = "#{pwd}/#{file}"
    if File.directory?(filename)                  # CHECK IF DIRECTORY
      recursive_dir_descend(filename,regexp,action)
    else
      if file =~ regexp
        eval action   # execute action on filename                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
      end
    end
  end
  Dir.chdir(olddir)
end
```